# How do I show the derivative does not exist for this complex valued function?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f(z)=\frac{xy(x+iy)}{|z|^2},z\neq 0$ and $f(z)=0,z=0$. I need to prove the derivative at $0$ does not exist. This is what I got so far and where I am stuck, $f'(0)=\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the complex derivative of $f$, then $f$ is differentiable at $z = 0$ if and only if the following limits exists:

$$ \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(z) - f(0)}{z} = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(z)}{z} = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2} $$

By considering $(x,y) = (t,t)$ with $t \to 0$, we get the limit

$$ \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^2}{2t^2} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} $$

while by considering $(x,y) = (t,0)$ with $t \to 0$ we get the limit

$$ \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{0}{t^2} = \lim_{t \to 0} 0 = 0 $$

and so the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you! I totally forgot you can approach a limit from different points in the complex plane

Answer (score 0):

Consider the points $(x,y)=(a,a)$.

Now, $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{a\to0}\frac{a.a}{2a^2}=1/2\neq0$